# Subversion 1.8.0 client working against a 1.6.11 server

Tags: svn

I recently upgraded my subversion client to 1.8.0, even though our company's subversion server is 1.6.11, since everywhere I checked it seemed like they should be compatible.

The basic commands work fine (update, commit, etc). The problem is that when I try to perform some more involved commands like relocates, or I try to generate a release from maven release-plugin. In there cases I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] svn: E175002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://mycompaniesserver.com/svn/repo/trunk/project'
[ERROR] svn: E175002: OPTIONS request on '/svn/repo/trunk/project' failed: 503 Service Unavailable
```

Which my fellow coworkers who use a range of clients from 1.6 to the latest 1.7 don't seem to get.

My guess is that Subversion 1.8 sends some HTTP OPTIONS commands which older versions of the client did not, and the subversion server's firewall o proxy (not subversion per se) is rejecting them.

Is there any way to prevent those newer format messages from being sent, aside from reverting to an older subversion client (since I already converted all my projects to the 1.8 format)? Or is there any clear rule that needs to be added to the subversion server's firewall so the 1.8 clients will work?

Edit: I went back to an 1.7.x client and everthing works fine, but I'd really like to find a way in which I could use the 1.8 client without having te involve the server's sysadmin.

Answer (score 2):

i had the same issue with subversion client 1.8.0 through tortoisesvn 1.8.0 while connecting to a subversion server 1.5.1 over a https-proxy. solved it by using an older subversion client version.

Comment: That's what I had to do too, as well as download again all my 1.8 format converted projects. I wish there was a way to disable those OPTIONS commands from being sent so I could use the new client.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose, you can read chapter ["HTTP client support based on neon has been removed"](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#neon-deleted) in Subversion 1.8 Release Notes, pay attention to server- and client-side configuration options for Skelta|Bulk mode and test client-server modes from table (discuss it with you Network Administrator) - you may move from bulk to skelta with 1.8

Another version - proxy|firewal in the middle block

> Unable to connect to a repository at URL

new changed activity of svn-client

> when Kerberos or NTLM authentication is used, ... add a 2 - 4 KB header per HTTP request and response

Answer (score 1):

IIRC this is a bug in 1.8.0. Install one of the later 1.8.x releases.

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem. Nothing to do with the settings it's just that the latest version of Tortoise does not work with the SVN version installed on my server. I downloaded a prior version of Tortoise and the problem was solved.

(had version 1.8, downloaded 1.7 and it worked. Interestingly; however, after upgrading SVN on the server to 1.8 Tortoise 1.8 still didn't work and I could only connect with Tortoise 1.7.

Comment: In my case, it cannot really be an issue with just Tortoise, because I had problems running several maven commands which use plain old svn.

Answer (score 1):

As another data point I had an issue with talking to a 1.6 server from a 1.8 client over http. There was some dodgy proxy in the way that claimed to be http 1.1 compliant. Subversion though really pushes the http protocol.

A 1.7 client has two http libraries: WebDAV and Serf. WebDAV was dropped in 1.8, leaving you with just the Serf http library.

I had to explicitly turn off chunked transfers in my svn 1.8 client's config file. Then everything worked (er, apart from any checkins that included a new file, sigh!).

See the first entry in [Known Issues in 1.8](https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#issues), and read up on `http-chunked-requests = no` in your `~/.subversion/servers` file

Answer (score 0):

I am sure this question might have answered elsewhere. However recently while working on my project i got the same issue and applying the solution given elsewhere i.e. commenting the

[image]

line given above in the image didn't worked for me as it was already commented out. FYI the file is located at the following in the local system
**strong text**C:\Documents and Settings_username_\Application Data\Subversion\servers

We were using Subversion eclipse plugin to do all the operations. The reason it occurs is because the subversion request is getting proxied that doesn't support few HTTP methods.

As solution i did following. In your eclipse IDE

Go to Window > Preferences > Network Connections. If the value in the "Active Provider: " is other than Direct then change it to Direct. Retry the operation your trying and it should work like a charm. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In my case was working the following solution:

1. Go to

   ```
   %APPDATA%\Subversion\servers
   ```
2. Add ad the end the following line:

   ```
     http-chunked-requests = no
   ```